# Haskell: Is there an idiomatic way to insert every item in a list into its own list?

Tags: list, haskell, idioms

I've been using `((:[]) <$> xs)` but if there is a more clear way I would love to use it.

edit: so many good answers guys! I don't think I can accept one because they are all good.

Answer (score 12):

I believe `map return` or `map pure` are good enough.

Comment: I'd argue that `(:[])` is clearer than return & less characters

Comment: @jozefg `pure` is even shorter.

Comment: True, but requires and import

Comment: `pure` is nicely clear, and concise, and importing `Applicative` can hardly be a problem, can it?

Comment: (:[]) is colloquially known as the "robot monkey operator" and is beautiful for that reason alone.

Comment: You're already importing `Applicative` if you're using `<$>`.

Comment: To me `map return` or `map pure` are like mental speed bumps when reading the code. I have think about why it works because `return` and `pure` are so generic - their behaviour depends on the context. With `(:[])` it's pretty clear though.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe No they're not, `return` has a consistent conceptual interpretation so `map return` is ultra-clear; I can read it faster/more fluently than `map (:[])`. (OK, perhaps it's just decades of monadic programming that makes that crystal clear - it feels clearer than `map pure`, probably because Applicative is more recent.)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this?

```
map (\x -> [x]) xs
```

Yours can work on any functor I think so this would be more idomatic for just lists.

Answer (score 4):

The split package provides a (Data.List.Split.)chunksOf function whose name is, IMO, more meaningful than the various map solutions (even if they are more idiomatic.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
[ [x] | x <- theList]
```

Maybe overkill for such a simple example, but depending on your context, maybe you can merge this step with some further processing of the singleton lists:

```
[f [x] + 13 | x <- theList]
```

Answer (score 2):

Tongue-in-cheek version:

```
import Data.List

groupBy (const . const False) xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `do` notation:

```
do { x <- xs; return [x] }
```