# How to convert list into nested list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I turn a list into the nested list such as:

```
[p,q,q]  -> [[p],[q],[q]]
```

I have tried this way:

```
return [2,5,6]  // But the result is wrong -> [[2,5,6]] (correct would be  [[2],[5],[6]] )
```

Implementation of `return` looks like this:

```
return x = [x]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Is there an idiomatic way to insert every item in a list into its own list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495179/haskell-is-there-an-idiomatic-way-to-insert-every-item-in-a-list-into-its-own-l), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772517/inverse-of-concat-transforming-a-flattened-list-into-a-nested-list/26772681, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815858/wraps-around-each-top-level-element-of-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply it every element of the list, not to the list itself, which can be achieved using [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:map):

```
map (\x -> [x]) [2, 5, 6]
```

or, equivalently

```
map (:[]) [2, 5, 6]
```

or, as you suggest, using `return` in place of `\x -> [x]`

```
map return [2, 5, 6]
```

Note that in the latter case, the type of the value returned will be `(Monad m) => [m a]`, which is more general than `[[a]]`.

Comment: Thank you, I could not achieve that..

Comment: This is why I wish we had a standard library function `singleton x = [x]`. `(:[])` just looks like a golfing technique and `return` is confusing since it's so general. `map singleton [2, 5, 6]` would look far more natural IMHO.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Very true. I typed `(:[])` and had an immediate doubt if it will work at all.

Comment: Part of learning Haskell is learning to abstract and generalize. `return` (or `pure`) is a pretty low hurdle to clear, relatively speaking.

Answer (score 2):

```
nest [] = []
nest (x:xs) = [x]:nest xs
```

`nest (x:xs) = [x]:nest xs`

This splits the input up in to the first value of the array (x) and the rest of the array (xs) and then puts the first value in to an array and puts it at the start of an array where the next value is the next part of the array.

`nest [] = []`

This terminates the recursion when the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension also works here:

```
toNested :: [a] -> [[a]]
toNested xs = [[x] | x <- xs]
```